# Data size of a MPMediaItem (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm programming a music player and I declare a NSMutableArray that keeps track of the songs that are played.

I'm wondering what could be the data size (average size) of a MPMediaItem.

I would like to make an array containing the information for each MPMediaItem played but I'm wondering if it's better to stock every MPMediaItem or only stock the information (string) about the songs (title, artist and album title).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those two things (the information vs. the MPMediaItem) are virtually the same thing! They are both just collections of strings. An MPMediaItem is a pointer to the item on disk, which is itself treated as just a lightweight collection of info (like an NSDictionary of NSStrings, which is basically what *you* would make anyway).

The only thing that is at all heavyweight is the act of gathering the info. For example, doing the initial MPMediaQuery can take time. But once you've got your answer, be it collections or media items or whatever, you can just store them. On the other hand, if you know in advance what info you are going to want, it does no harm to collect it up front - though this, too, will take some time. For example, I do this:

```
MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery albumsQuery];
NSArray* albums = [query collections];
NSArray* titles = [albums valueForKey: @"repItemTitle"];
```

Where `repItemTitle` is defined in a category on MPMediaItemCollection:

```
- (id) repItemTitle {
    return [[self representativeItem] 
        valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
}
```

In general, though, I would say: Don't Optimize Prematurely! Get the app working. If you find out later that there is some sort of performance / memory problem, then if you've structured things correctly, changing the model implementation behind the scenes will be trivial. (But I don't think you'll have to.)

Comment: Thanks!! Really interresting!